# Convert a Negative Number with Parentheses to a Minus in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, negative-number

I have a MYSQL database with Negative numbers that are enclosed in parenthesis 
eg. (14,500) which is supposed to be -14500. 

I am storing the numbers as varchar. I am trying to convert all the numbers to a double or float format and also format the negative numbers with a minus sign. 
My code:

```
select case 
   when substr(gross_d,1,1) = '(' then
       ltrim('(') and rtrim(')') *-1
   else 
      (gross_d)
   end gross_d_num
from buy;
convert(gross_d_num,Double);
```

The problem with my current method is all the negative numbers with the parenthesis are converted to zero. Is there a different method to get my result.

edit:

I also removed the *-1 to see if the Parenthesis is removed and I get a value of zero.

Comment: that's because `ltrim('(') and rtrim(')') * -1` is always zero no matter what gross_d is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
convert (
    case 
       when gross_d LIKE '(%)' THEN CONCAT('-', REPLACE(REPLACE(gross_d, ')', ''), '(', ''))
       else gross_d
    end, decimal(19,6))
```

Here, you are trimming parenthesis only. This becomes zero when you multiply by -1

```
ltrim('(') and rtrim(')') *-1
```

Comment: I tried using the code but at line 5 MYSQL reports that there is an error in syntax. I also added in select and from into the code. I tried using cast and I got the same error.

Comment: I removed the convert statement and tried it with just select case and the negative numbers are being represented perfectly. I am going to look at how to use the convert or cast statements and I will post my working solution.

Comment: thank you for your help it worked. I had to at first remove all the commas from each value in the column. I used SET field_name = replace( replace(field_name, ',', ''), '"', '' ). Then I used the convert procedure.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Lastever: you're welcome. Please vote up and/or accept my answer then (the up and the tick on the left)

Answer (score 0):

```
CONVERT( 
    IF( gross_d LIKE '(%)' 
        ,CONCAT( '-', SUBSTR( gross_d, 1, LENGTH( gross_d ) - 2 ) )
        ,gross_d )
,DECIMAL );
```

Answer (score 0):

At our company we don't have control over currency formatting used by external parties uploading excel sheets. We currently use this to convert the currencies and add a case whenever something new shows up :

```
SET @netSale := '$ (154.00)';

SELECT CONVERT (

CASE 
       when @netSale LIKE '$ (%)' THEN CONCAT('-', REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@netSale, '$ ', ''), ')', ''), '(', ''))
       when @netSale LIKE '(%)' THEN CONCAT('-', REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@netSale, '$ ', ''), ')', ''), '(', ''))
       else REPLACE(REPLACE(@netSale,'$',''),',', '')
    END, DECIMAL(10,2)
)
```

This deals with most formatting styles we have encountered and is especially useful when loading a converted CSV file to a table.